# Getting all rows from a column of an sql db using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem... I want to show all the emails that I have in a SQL Server table in a label.

Here is the code :

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    connection.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select Email from Clients",connection);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while(dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
        label.Text = dr[0].ToString() + "<br />";   
    }

    dr.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

`dr` is a `SqlDataReader` declared above and `cmd` is a `SqlCommand`.

This code shows me only an email in the label, I guess that I misunderstand the functions of `SqlDataReader` ...

Please help if anyone has any idea ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading all the emails in the loop and you are putting the email to the label.

```
while(dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read();
        label.Text = dr[0].ToString() + "<br />";   
    }
```

With each run of the loop you are overwritting the label value, so finally the last email will be displayed. This is the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and change your code like this:-

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(dr.Read())
{
    sb.Append(dr[0].ToString() + "<br />");
}

//Finally add it to your label
    label.Text = sb.ToString();
```

`dr.Read()` will iterate through your results in `SqlDataReader` object. Apart, from this there is no need of this line - `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` remove it from your code and use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to automatically dispose your expensive resources.

Comment: @ArbërKuçi - You're welcome, as a newbie to SO, I would suggest you to go through this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  and accept the answer if that helped.

Comment: @ArbërKuçi - As per your original post you said:- `I want to show all the emails that I have in a SQL Server table in a label.` so that's why I use `StringBuilder` You can check about its performance benefits :) You unaccepted so was curious to know the reason.